# "more" command doesn't work as expected in initramfs

Tags: initramfs, dmesg, busybox, more

I'm trying to watch `dmesg` output in (initramfs) but command output has more lines than a screen. So I see only the end of `dmesg` output.
Busybox v1.21.1 has `more` command, but `dmesg | more` somehow doesn't work as expected (it shows complete output without possibility scroll).

Why it doesn't work and are there any other ways in initramfs to watch `dmesg` output?

Comment: You can redirect the output of `dmesg` to a file using `dmesg > file.txt` then open the file and scroll the output

Comment: @singrium "more <file>"  also shows full output without possibility scroll

Comment: Yeah that's right, but it is strange that `dmesg | more` does not work for you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using VMware, none of `more` or `|` options worked. But <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> is working in Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Try `dmesg | less` instead. `less` is a more advanced cousin of `more`. It should give you the option to scroll.